# A sufficient condition for normality of a subgroup.

Tags: group-theory

> A subgroup $H$ of a group $G$ is called *normal* if it remains stable under the conjugation action of $G$ on itself. In other words $H$ is normal in $G$ if $gHg^{-1}=H$ for every $g\in G$.

I have found the following problem concerning the normality of a subgroup as an exercise somewhere:

> Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ and $[G:H]=m$ and for every $1\leq i \leq m-1$ the condition $x^i\in H$ implies $x\in H$. Show that $H$ is normal in $G$.

I have tried to solve it indirectly, i.e., I supposed that $H$ has at least one conjugate other than itself, then how can I reach a contradiction. However I couldn't find a contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $h \in H$ and $g \in G$ and consider $E:= \{gh^ig^{-1} \ : \ i=1,...,m \} = \{(ghg^{-1})^i \ : \ i=1,...,m \}$.

If there exists $i\in \{1,...,m-1\}$ such that $gh^ig^{-1} \in H$, by assumption $ghg^{-1} \in H$.

If not, let $H_1,...,H_{m-1}$ be the cosets of $H$ in $G$ not equal to $H$. Let's consider 2 cases:

1) If there exists two elements of $E$ in the same coset, i.e. there exists $1 \leq i<j \leq m$ such that $gh^ig^{-1}, gh^jg^{-1} \in H_l$, then $(gh^ig^{-1})^{-1}gh^jg^{-1}=gh^{j-i}g^{-1} \in H$ where $1 \leq j-i \leq m-1$, a contradiction.

2) If no two elements of $E$ are in the same coset, then $E$ is a set of coset representatives. Therefore there exists $i$ such that $g \in gh^ig^{-1}H$ and $g=gh^ig^{-1}h_1$ with $h_1 \in H$. We conclude that $g = h_1h^i \in H$ and $ghg^{-1} \in H$.

In all cases, $ghg^{-1} \in H$ and $H$ is normal.

Comment: You made a small typo in the first case: $j-1$ should be $j-i$.

Comment: @VáclavMordvinov Thank you, I edited!

Comment: Not sure, but don't you mean $g=h_1h^i$ in the second case? Instead of $g=h^ih_1$?

Comment: @VáclavMordvinov You are right again, thank you!

Comment: Dear Giard, It seems that case 2 in the second part of the reasoning also leads to a contradiction. Because if $g\in H$ then all the members of $E$ belong to $H$ and so $E$ can not be a set of coset representatives of $H$ in $G$.

Comment: I agree, it leads to a contradiction (I also assumed that there's no $i$ such that $gh^ig^{-1} \in H$ which is another contradiction).